# flow union types not working in recursive call

Tags: javascript, flowtype, union-types

I'm having trouble with flow with typechecking a custom union type that allows either a `Function`, `Promise` or `Array` containing either `false` or an instance of a `Plugin` class.

The code works without typechecking and allows the developer to nest a `Plugin` or `false` inside any other allowed type, however, I can't seem to get the type system to allow the code without any errors.

I'm working with the assumption that we can use recursive types eg `type T = false | Array<T>` so the type could be either false or an array containing another `T` type. I read in a github comment that recursive types or allowed, however, could not find a code example.

```js
// @flow

type object = {}
type Plugins =
    false
  | Plugin
  | () => Plugins
  | Array<Plugins>
  | Promise<Plugins>

class Plugin {
  name: string
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}

class Engine {
  params = {}
  plugins = {}
  constructor(params: object) {
    this.params = params
  }
  pipe(plugin: Plugins): Engine {
    // do nothing if plugins is false
    if (plugin === false) {
      return this 
    }
    else if (typeof plugin === 'function') {
      this.pipe(plugin())
    }
    // get plugin from inside a Promise
    else if (plugin instanceof Promise) {
      plugin.then(plugin => this.pipe(plugin))
    } 
    // iterate over each item of an array
    else if (Array.isArray(plugin)) {
      plugin.forEach(plugin => this.pipe(plugin))
    }
    // initialize each plugin
    else if (plugin instanceof Plugin) {
      this.plugins[plugin.name] = plugin
    }
    // return this for chaining
    return this
  }
}

const engine = new Engine({ name: 'one'})
    .pipe(new Plugin('plugin-one'))
    .pipe([new Plugin('plugin-two')])
    .pipe(Promise.resolve([new Plugin('plugin-three')]))
    .pipe(() => new Plugin('plugin-four'))
    // should cause a flow type error
    .pipe(true)
    // I would like this to work deeply nested in any acceptable type
    .pipe([() => Promise.resolve([() => [Promise.resolve([new Plugin('plugin-five')])]])])

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(engine)
}, 20)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

I have tried multiple different type definitions with varying degrees of success, however, they generally fix the warnings, but no longer catch the type errors.

This was trying to set the final type apart from the wrapper types

```
type PluginTypes = false | Plugin
type Plugins = 
    Array<PluginTypes> 
  | Promise<PluginTypes> 
  | () => PluginTypes
```

This will prevent the errors by adding `Plugins` to the union type, however, the typechecking seems to no longer work.

```
type Plugins = 
    false
  | Plugin
  | Plugins
  | Array<Plugins> 
  | Promise<Plugins> 
  | () => Plugins
```

[https://flow.org/try/#example](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1LARgFZYDGKoAvKAN4C+qmOACtAK4DmAlgHYDOFioQaEgBDaDywDQAH1DN23KbIAUASgoA+Oa068loAIIAnIyLQAeebp4b9jI7AC2HCZZ3cbyYtBE8+V7mopLhFHLAAuUB4UI242KWJYXhiWUlgjZRCw9SopQRQACxcAOiycSjKpOjpEb18+AFEuXRxcwQwRU0c+SlopDHdeCmo6QUTko1SUdOUOrp5I-CJSHLzQQpK50J7QLe6q-o5sWcHIgN5VSKaWoKFQEFAAE1hQLlgN5tAOSF3BvhdhGIJGtvqATgouBRyJRROIsKs7oIjFgUCwjJCNjw1qMhFg4V8fsp0NhYD8BhCoZQAOSQFhcUgcJJUhGIzHFDBHLDg3RqVTYtYPNgo34UyAORxfXgcR44ERycUuSR3PESAlg8m6SXRET0rCk+VORUsu4a7jFQpYLjcwLkLRsjnHU1cVR8u40UACsAcFBYUw+3AAN19oCwImIBS+Pol+p1oE6pjQaxVOFBymMCeKLnTZmtzuNQidxUg6QaYYKuc06yKPHZnNzLv5dwe3G9HDEHAAXjhQ+GRbok-jU06tSgdcQ9T9zvn8tX2X8ANqFsoAXWGTsbQgeyNR6KrAOLRlA4ZELeaa23aIx1YONXGPFg0CwxTgbGUwSw8FA124XKor1CESgFSSRYFSNCukItbHFwH7aBCyhUk6AC0IHMhBghQVy84wZ+5wIchKDwLAzLLuhoCYco9iGhIxTIve0BBso2GwXhiGDEhhTIqBqikWRFFqJWOFwTybEQkhxZomhnpRAUsAsNAjxHiILCqnKMAIOsDAhiY6TSQAJA0AAe2CkA0OlGGsFEpPC0kAJKgER8mKdAHAANY4Ji6wvERRiuU8WBYAMaCvFg0RYIpgQ6sFYbjhgo54I+mnYNJFHzgJtoGs4NF0Q+jFpeoGXzlRWVPjlDFYUJrHIZAHBBiRPGkaRiB8kAA)

Thanks for any help

Comment: I played with it a while, and couldn't figure it out either. However, I think the simpler/better solution would just be to make a pipe function for each type i.e. pipe, pipeFunction, pipePromise, pipeArray, etc.

Comment: @m0meni Thanks for your suggestion. I think that would work, but it defeats the purpose of having recursive types housing the plugins. With the above you can nest any plugin in any type.

Comment: Recursive types are indeed allowed. A demonstration with `type Tree<T> = Array<Tree<T>> | T`: [Try Flow example](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AFQE5ZYA8uAfKALygCC++AhmqYSeRQD57KQCuAdgGMUAS1j9QAWwYBrLAGURkjNCwEiACgCUALjyti-XpIBGWfBQDeiUKEIpe+CQG0AuogC+iPkNHipslgAclgAzihYACbqWNp6MYbGZhag1rb2ji4AjAA0oM7OAEx5AMyueQAsru5e3gLCYhLScorKqgCS-ABuDNAi0axx+kSJpuZWNqAgoAAkAGJw8ACiAB7Ywkv0sPiTGU75AOQMBzV1vo0BciHhUZ09fQOausMkRmMpaVNg84ur6yibfDbXZYBz7Zy5fJFPJHE6VaqeIA)

Comment: @synthet1c I just [filed a bug report](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6738) about the object construction type inference bug I described in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Precedence issue

You can spot one error if you [run your type definition through](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEMCeAHOACACgGwFcBzASygGdsBeAHSm0ewDMBDfCuexgHzyLJRu2PgAoAlDQB8-EuQrC+AQQBOK1mgA8BOZSmK8KiAFtSnbQPlSQAGhAQMMUtArJQrNRADuuDwlcorABuEKQAJrYgAEbqYADWcDAAyhisYOTEyDAqhHB28nAqMLjqxMasyGwceSAAVhQAHgBCsQnJrMZwADLkcJXsnHapKpwqyNGsUWj40JEYKuQwAOrhMAAWyAAcAAxDRpxL6hjj83CjQX12KnAAjoSk1yWsZRVIVYMgnKb91XYUGfg4ABFQgQeA-D4wSYrMLrZAAJjs2VYpHwGQAwiZyuMoNBLiBCJwACqTALvOAAXwpQA) the [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) code formatter:

```js
type Plugins =
  | false
  | Plugin
  | (() => Plugins | Array<Plugins> | Promise<Plugins>)
```

As you can see, your top-level `Plugins` type wouldn’t accept an `Array` or a `Promise`, because the return value `Plugins` had higher **precedence** than the function `() => Plugins`. You can [fix that by **adding parentheses**](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEMCeAHOACACgGwFcBzASygGdsBeAHSm0ewDMBDfCuexgHzyLJRu2PgApRAShoA+fiXIUJwvgEEATmtZoAPAXmVpyvGogBbUp10CF0kABoQEDDFLQKyUKw0QA7ri8I7iisAG4QpAAm9iAARppgANZwMADKGKxg5MTIMGqEcA4KcGowuJrEpqzIbBwFIABWFAAeAELxSamspnAAMuRw1eycDulqnGrIsawxaPjQ0Rhq5DAA6pEwABbIABwADCMmnCuaGJOLcOMhAw5qcACOhKS3ZawVVUg1wyCc5oO1DhQsvg4ABFQgQeB-L4waZrCKbZAAJgcuVYpHwWQAwmZKpMoNBriBCJwACrTIKfOAAXypQA) around your `() => Plugins` function type:

```js
type Plugins =
  | false
  | Plugin
  | (() => Plugins)
  | Array<Plugins>
  | Promise<Plugins>
```

### Flow bug where object construction results in `any`

That’s a step forward, but when you [apply this change to your original code](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1LARgFZYDGKoAvKAN4C+qmOACtAK4DmAlgHYDOFioQaEgBDaDywDQAH1DN23KbIAUygJQUAfHNadeapaACCAJxMi0AHnl6emw4xOwAthwnXd3O8mLQRPPhtuaikuEWcsAC5QHhQTbjYpYlheOJZSWBNlMIiNKilBFAALNwA6HJxKCqk6OkRffz4AUS49HHzBDBFzZz5KWikMT14KajpBZNSTdJRM5S6enmj8IlI8gtBisoXwvtAd3prBjmx54eig-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), you will see that `.pipe(true)` now fails to throw the desired error. Using the feature of Try Flow to identify the type of the element under the cursor, I found why this happens by [adding some test code](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1LARgFZYDGKoAvKAN4C+qmOACtAK4DmAlgHYDOFioQaEgBDaDywDQAH1DN23KbIAUygJQUAfHNadeapaACCAJxMi0AHnl6emw4xOwAthwnXd3O8mLQRPPhtuaikuEWcsAC5QHhQTbjYpYlheOJZSWBNlMIiNKilBFAALNwA6HJxKCqk6OkRffz4AUS49HHzBDBFzZz5KWikMT14KajpBZNSTdJRM5S6enmj8IlI8gtBisoXwvtAd3prBjmx54eig-WiWtpChUBBQABNYUC5YLdbQDkh94b43MIxBINj9QGcFFwKORKKJxFh1vdBCYsCgWCYoVseBtxkIsPDvr9lOhsLBfkNIdDKABySAsLikDgpamIpFY0oYE5YCF6dQGe64wSPNiov6UyBOZzfXgcJ44ERySVuST3fESQngil6aWxEQMrBkxUuZWs+5a7ilYpYLg84LkbTszmnc1cNT8oQ0UAbR4cFBYcx+3AAN39oCwImIRW+fqlhr1oG65jQGzVODBylMSdKbkzFltrtNQhdpUgmSaEaK+a0mxKPA5XPzbpx3rA3F9HDEHAAXjhw5GxXoUwT0y6dSg9cQDb9LoXCrWOf8ANrFioAXVGLub90eKLRGJrgNLJlAkZEbdaG136MxtaOdUmsWl7bEN24lTeWHgoFfXG5VDe4RRKAABEKRYMBoA0GoADciCPIwLBkFaJ7ojwmSgPAvolFCAAGbYoB20A-lgOGlKAAAqRQ4HgHyzFKeDdDERQIHwxQiEhVGbAw3x8DhepoKRPgpGh0BYKUcBsMooSft+rRvso-4VNE1JgdSUEbPWpy-l+lzKNSLoALSqU29yadyi7aTokJ6YZKDwLALKru6ghmcojjGhIpQoiJIbKBZMm6fpwwGcUKJYI5JlCK56jVpZgWGaW6Iss5DxgDwzEsNATwniILDqgqMAIFx2BhmYmQtqAAAkTQAB7YKQTRlSYGlOtyaQIhVACSGGwJl2XQBwADWOBYpsrz2SYg3PFgWBDGgH6xFg2XBPxCbEJOGDjngonFSqQiPK5i4xfaRquJ53mwNAvlHRoJ2Lu5Z1iRdV3mXFww2cFkAcCGEWrk5TmIAYQA) near the bottom:

```js
const initialEngine = new Engine({ name: "one" });
// In Try Flow, put the cursor within `initialEngine`. The type is `any`.
```

`new Engine(…)` **returns a value of type `any`** instead of type `Engine` like you would expect. This `any` is why no calls to `.pipe` afterward throw an error, even when they should.

You can work around this by **manually annotating** the constructed engine as an `Engine`, using either a type annotation or variable assignment:

```js
console.log(
  (new Engine({ name: 'one'}): Engine)
    .pipe(new Plugin('plugin-one'))
    // …
)
```

```js
const initialEngine: Engine = new Engine({ name: 'one'})

console.log(
  initialEngine
    .pipe(new Plugin('plugin-one'))
    // …
)
```

Ideally you could make `new Engine(…)` return an `Engine`, but I think this is a bug in Flow, not something to be fixed by changing your code. My evidence is that removing the following code inside your `pipe` method also fixes the issue:

```js
    // get plugin from inside a Promise
    else if (plugin instanceof Promise) {
      plugin.then(plugin => this.pipe(plugin))
    }
```

I have [**created an issue** on Flow’s bug tracker](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6738) about this, demonstrating the problem with a more minimal example. The bug requires a strangely specific combination of factors to trigger; it’s just your luck that you met them all.

Until the bug is fixed, you should use the workaround of adding a type annotation.

#### Edit: a better workaround

As [wchargin](https://github.com/wchargin) mentioned [in the GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6738#issuecomment-412765028), you can also work around this problem by explicitly annotating `Engine`’s `constructor` as returning `void`:

```js
class Engine {
  // …
  constructor(params: object): void {
    this.params = params
  }
  // …
}
```

If you do this, you won’t have to add an `Engine` annotation to every place you construct an `Engine` object.

### The final code

Combine these two fixes to get your final, working code ([in Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#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-5jsIay7iIkGtLq9F2mOPJ1IsPCwNAWClHAbDKKEWDwKAkrcImVCgBU0QAEQpFgSmgDQM6CEBApcJJOjJgGPYALSqRGWmgDpibEXpUlisoRnDMZKB3BG5EWVZyiOB2EilFsAnQBuyg2fp9mOcKzlFFsWBuaBzKeeoAG2QZegOSZn67OZ4ExEUsAsNA5ygMQIgsDWpYAGIItMDBbmYmTZQAJE0AAe2CkE0dUmLqnlpBa2UACrzMx0AIgc5xYFgQxoMZemxFghVctsm4KlJdwmPcDrxRO1mJSO7auL5-mCUFxG7doxHeQdwlHYF1nJWF6UcBusXke57mIAYQA)):

```js
// @flow

type object = {}
type Plugins =
    false
  | Plugin
  | (() => Plugins)
  | Array<Plugins>
  | Promise<Plugins>

class Plugin {
  name: string
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}

class Engine {
  params = {}
  plugins = {}

  // type the constructor as returning `void` to work around
  // https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6738
  constructor(params: object): void {
    this.params = params
  }

  pipe(plugin: Plugins): Engine {
    // do nothing if plugins is false
    if (plugin === false) {
      return this
    }
    else if (typeof plugin === 'function') {
      this.pipe(plugin())
    }
    // get plugin from inside a Promise
    else if (plugin instanceof Promise) {
      plugin.then(plugin => this.pipe(plugin))
    } 
    // iterate over each item of an array
    else if (Array.isArray(plugin)) {
      plugin.forEach(plugin => this.pipe(plugin))
    }
    // initialize each plugin
    else if (plugin instanceof Plugin) {
      this.plugins[plugin.name] = plugin
    }
    // return this for chaining
    return this
  }
}

console.log(
  new Engine({ name: "one" })
    .pipe(new Plugin('plugin-one'))
    .pipe([new Plugin('plugin-two')])
    .pipe(Promise.resolve([new Plugin('plugin-three')]))
    .pipe(() => new Plugin('plugin-four'))
    // should cause a Flow type error
    // $ExpectError
    .pipe(true)
    // The following deeply-nested parameter now works
    .pipe([() => Promise.resolve([() => [Promise.resolve([new Plugin('plugin-five')])]])])
)
```

Comment: thanks so much for your in depth answer with examples, debugging tips and opening an issue with the developers for this bug. I will have to do more research into flow and debugging tools, I read through the docs but still don't understand some of the concepts and don't know if vim is a suitable editor for it. I will assign the bounty when it's available.